# C - reading multiple file streams

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, filestream

Im writing my own simplified version of the classic UNIX program 'wc' (word count). It counts number of lines, words, and characters. All these features work fine. But where i run into trouble is when im trying to read multiple files from *argv[x]. I need to make every variable into an array, and run the whole process through loops to achieve what im looking for.

My program returns a segmentation fault. Something is not being assigned into the arrays at some point in the code, and i can't seem to figure out exactly where that is.

Any help is much appreciated :)

```
/*
 *      [PROGRAM]   wc (word count)
 *       [AUTHOR]   Jesper M. Olsen @ jm0.codes
 *         [DATE]   September 9th 2015
 *      [PURPOSE]   Returns number of lines, words, and characters in a file
 *
 *  [DESCRIPTION]   This program is meant to be utilized as a handy little browsing tool.
 *                  For instance, while moving through the filesystem of a programming archive,
 *                  just type 'wc <filename>' and you will get number of lines, words and characters returned promptly.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
        return -1;

    int numL[argc]; /* initialize array value placeholders */
    int numW[argc];
    int numC[argc];
    int getC[argc];
    int getW[argc];

    int setNull;
    for (setNull = 1; setNull <= argc-1; setNull++) { /* assign ZERO to value placeholders */
        numL[setNull] = 0;
        numW[setNull] = 0;
        numC[setNull] = 0;
        getW[setNull] = 0;
    }

    int x;
    FILE *fOp[argc-1];
    for (x = 1; x <= argc-1; x++) { /* open file stream for each file */
        fOp[x] = fopen(argv[x], "r");
        if (fOp[x] == NULL)
            return -1;
    }

        int y;
        for (y = 1; (getC[y] = getc(fOp[y])) != EOF; y++) {
            if (getC[y] == '\n') numL[y]++;
            if (getC[y] == ' ' || getC[y] == '\n' || getC[y] == '\t') getW[y] = 0;
            else if (getW[y] == 0) { 
                getW[y] = 1;
                numW[y]++; 
            } numC[y]++;
        } 

        int z;
        for (z = 1; z <= argc-1; z++) { /* close files */
            fclose(fOp[z]);
        }

    int c;
    for (c = 1; c <= argc-1; c++) {
        printf("[%s] %dL %dW %dC\n", argv[c], numL[c], numW[c], numC[c]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Note - You never use index `0` of any array in your code .

Comment: Please attach debugger backtrace output, so we know what line the segfault is at.

Comment: `FILE *fOp[argc-1];` should be `FILE *fOp[argc];` and I also prefer seeing `< argc` rather than `<= argc-1`

Comment: So load up your debugger and debug the program.

Comment: the code is trying to perform a `wc` operation on a file, and is trying to perform the operation on several files.   The code would be much clearer if the collection of the `wc` parameters for a single file were in a sub function.  The pass the file names to the sub function, one at a time, from a loop in `main()`  In general, the code would be much simpler because the data variables would be single instances rather than arrays.   Also, from the viewpoint of the user, it does not matter where the lines/characters/words information is output, so output each line in the sub function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem may be
 here -

```
 for (y = 1; (getC[y] = getc(fOp[y])) != EOF; y++) {
        if (getC[y] == '\n') numL[y]++;
        if (getC[y] == ' ' || getC[y] == '\n' || getC[y] == '\t') getW[y] = 0;
        else if (getW[y] == 0) { 
            getW[y] = 1;
            numW[y]++; 
        } numC[y]++;
    }
```

As arrays can `argc` number of elements but with this loop you may have read and stored integers more than `argc` in `getC` .  Thus getting *Seg Fault* .

But we don't know what it inside files we can't be sure.

Try increasing size of arrays .

Note - It is better to initialize array starting with index `0`. In this code you haven't  use index `0`.

Comment: I found the seg fault after running some tests, and sure enough. It was placed in the for loop you're describing ^^. It's a logical error, of course that  produced an error. I just put a while in the for loop, so it would evaluate each file as intended. Here's the working code: http://codepad.org/6KbtiriR

Comment: @JesperOlsen  I didn't know what was in file so wasn't sure enough .  But sure your code runs fine now . Cheers !!

Comment: @JesperOlsen  I was surprised first but now taking close look `y` wasn't restricted in that previous `for loop`  which was needed as it would get index out of bound reason for error.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause a segfault when you reach the last file

```
FILE *fOp[argc-1];

for (x = 1; x <= argc-1; x++) { /* open file stream for each file */
    fOp[x] = fopen(argv[x], "r");
    if (fOp[x] == NULL)
        return -1;
}
```

because the array is not large enough. It should be

```
FILE *fOp[argc];
```

The mistake would be easier to see if you used

```
< argc
```

instead of

```
<= argc-1
```

in your loops.

Comment: @ameyCU, nope, he is indexing an array with `argc-1` elements by `argc-1`.

Comment: I guess he does not use index `0` because he is not interested in `argv[0]`

Comment: What about it? He does not use it.

Comment: Ohh ,  my bad  Got confused .You were talking about `argv` .